# Get data from aspx.cs page to aspx page

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, datalist

So I am using a jquery plug in that allows me to change the order of things in a list by dragging and dropping them. 
So my goal is to be able to grab a list of my objects (AlertInfo) and using it in a javascript function. 
I was able to use a json webservice call in a test project to pass the data to the page.
But we don't have a webservice page now so I tried to grab it from a aspx.cs page and it hasn't worked.

///Aspx page:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "~/Alerts/GetAlerts",
   data: "{}",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        var data = eval("(" + msg.d + ")");
        jQuery.each(data, function (rec) {
        AlertList[AlertList.length] = new objAlert(this.id, this.title, this.details,               JSONDateSerializationFix(this.startdate), JSONDateSerializationFix(this.enddate));
        UpdateDisplayList();
     })
     },
     error: function (msg) {
        alert("BRAD" + msg);
     }
```

The issue is that the Alerts page in "URL /Alerts/GetAlerts" is Alerts.aspx.cs.  I can't figure out if I can use this ajax command to call a method in a aspx.cs page.
//Code behind page aspx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
 //[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetAlerts()
{
  List<AlertInfo> list = AlertInfo.GetTestAlerts();
  return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(list);
}

public List<AlertInfo> GetAlertsList()
{
  List<AlertInfo> list = AlertInfo.GetTestAlerts();
  return list; ;
}
```

So I was hoping that I could load data into an asp control (dataList) and then grab the data

//code behind page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataListAlertList.DataSource = GetAlertsList();
    dataListAlertList.DataBind();
}
public static List<AlertInfo> GetTestAlerts()
{
            List<AlertInfo> list = new List<AlertInfo>();
            list.Add(new AlertInfo("0", "Alert 1 Title", "Alert 1 Detail", "10/10/2010", "10/10/2011"));
            list.Add(new AlertInfo("1", "Alert 2 Title", "Alert 2 Detail", "10/10/2010", "10/10/2011"));
            return list;
```

}

//.aspx page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var a1 = $("#dataListAlertList").val();
    // do fun stuff now.
}
```

But I keep getting undefined....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't need to preload. Ended up using the datalist and then changed how it was formatted. In the document ready function I grabbed the divs and applied the properties that needed to be set.